# PetaPoco Query View Always Returns NULLS

Tags: c#, sql-server, petapoco

I have the below view in SQL Server represented using PetaPoco in my C# application:

```
/// <summary>   Rep Level Keys. </summary>
[TableName("vXPATRepLevelKeys")]
[ExplicitColumns]
public partial class vXPATRepLevelKeys : dbo.Record<vXPATRepLevelKeys>
{
    /// <summary>   Gets or sets the RepLevelKey. </summary>
    public string RepLevelKey { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I attempt to select from the view using:

```
var result = _database.Fetch<xPAT.vXPATRepLevelKeys>("SELECT * FROM vXPATRepLevelKeys").OrderBy(x => x.RepLevelKey);
var asStrings = result.Select(x => x.RepLevelKey).ToList();
```

I just get a list of NULL values. `asStrings` has 33 items in the list, all being NULL. However, when I run the above view myself, I get 33 non-null results.

I'm new to PetaPoco (tbh, I'm not even sure if it is a PetaPoco related issue) and have inherited this application, which I'm attempting to add this new view to so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `[ExplicitColumns]` attribute, you must use the `[Column]` attribute on each property

```
[Column]
public string RepLevelKey { get; set; }
```

Comment: Great thank you Eduardo! I can't believe I missed that!